# Ethernet port not connecting at boot up Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking

I am trying to connect thru my Ethernet port on my Dell desktop computer. I just installed a switch to connect my ooma phone and computer on the same connection in my room. When I boot up the computer I see the port connect, but once its booting to Ubuntu the port turns off. My wireless does work fine and I dual boot this same computer with Windows 10 and works just fine with the switch. Once logged in I run the following command: sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off  The port turns on and I can connect, but at a very slow speed. I have FIOS 100/100MBPS internet speed. I tried changing the 100 to 1000, but received an error of not supported. 
Here's some info to understand my problem:

```
-Vostro-270s:~$ dmesg | grep "eth0"
[    0.738498] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl at 0xffffc90000c6a000, a4:1f:72:88:bc:89, XID 0c900880 IRQ 28
[    0.738500] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   26.987264] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down
[   26.987268] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down
[   26.987321] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   27.094342] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  525.696956] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down
[  525.697005] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down
[  525.697044] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  852.138799] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl at 0xffffc90000c6a000, a4:1f:72:88:bc:89, XID 0c900880 IRQ 28
[  852.138802] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[  852.265177] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down
[  873.162612] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready


Vostro-270s:~$ ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: no

Vostro-270s:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password:
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 70:18:8b:af:0b:c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-38-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.170 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7800000-f787ffff memory:f7880000-f788ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: a4:1f:72:88:bc:89
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ea104000-ea104fff memory:ea100000-ea103fff
```

Let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: What driver is the ethernet port using? Easiest just to look in Connection Information in the network menu. Cheers, Al

Comment: I am using r8169. When I get home I can send a screen shot of this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The r8169 ethernet driver is buggy. Using Synaptic, install `r8168-dkms`. Turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS.

Start Synaptic, click the RELOAD icon, then the SEARCH icon, type in `r8168-dkms`, mark it for installation, then click the APPLY icon. Quit Synaptic. Reboot the computer. Then disable `secure boot` in the BIOS.

That should solve the problem. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks for the info and I did what you said and fix most of my problems. The only thing now is my speed. I have FIOS 100/100 down/up and all I am getting is 7Mbps. I have tried changing the port speed with

Comment: sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on

Comment: But did not work. Please let me know how I can get the max speed. By the way, I dual boot to Windows 10 and get 95Mbps.

Comment: What happens if you connect the computer directly to your FIOS adapter/modem? Eliminate the switch/etc. Is it a gigabyte switch? Please remember to vote/accept my answer as the solution to your ethernet problem. Cheers, Al

Comment: Eliminating the switch did the trick. Thanks you for all your help. Now time to buy a new switch. Thanks